# React markdown image alignment with Contentful markdown

Tags: reactjs, markdown, contentful

I'm using [Contentful](https://www.contentful.com/) for storing content for articles and [React markdown](https://github.com/rexxars/react-markdown) for parsing and it works very well. But i don't know what what exat to do when it comes to alignment of images like two images side by side.

Is there there a way to see in the markdown how many images are renderad? Then i could do alignment based on how many images there is in the markdown

Comment: You provide very little context. How does it look right now? How should it look? Do you render to an HTML web app or is it something else, electron maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You can insert some HTML (which is not the ideal solution) in the markdown like `<img='img' class='align-left' />` you can also have a separate field of type asset list and you get these image separately and add them to your HTML

Answer (score -1):

You could style images using the next-sibling selector.

Perhaps something like this:

```
img + img { /* styles for any image directly after another image */ }
```